# How to create a simple unordered tree(not BST) in java with given node pairs(u,v)?

Tags: java, tree, nodes

Problem is I don't understand how to create a tree. I have gone through many code examples on trees but I don't even know how to work with/handle a node and hence I don't understand how the ***node class*** works(*that was present in all the program examples* ). When i try to use methods such as appendChild(as mentioned in java docs),I get an error,and I am asked to create one such appendChild method inside that ***node class*** within the main program. Couldn't understand why that happened.

I am given integer pairs((u,v) meaning there is an edge between u & v) of nodes and I also need to know if any Element-to-node conversion is required for using u and v(of type integer) as nodes.

Please bear with me since my basics are weak. Little explanation on how the entire thing works/functions would be very helpful.
Thank you.

EDIT 1: I went through the following links:(hardly found anything on just **unordered** trees) http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Trees/code/BST.java http://www.newthinktank.com/2013/03/binary-tree-in-java/ . Tried to modify these codes to meet my own purpose but failed.
I only got a blurry idea and that is not enough for implementation. I am trying to make a simple unordered tree,for which i am given u v pairs like:
(4,5) (5,7) (5,6). I just need to join (4<--5),(5<--7) and (5<--6). So how do I write a node class that only joins one node to the prev node? Besides,to do **only** this,do I need to bother myself with leftchild,rightchild? If not,how will I be able to traverse the tree and do similar operations such as height diameter calculation etc later?

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: AFAIK there is no 'Node' class in the standard Java libraries to model a node in a tree or graph. So you'll have to hand-code that yourself. Or, are you already working with a 'Node' class and are puzzled about the way it works. If so, post the code.

Comment: @aquaraga Thank you for your response. I have added more details for the ease of understanding of my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Well Its not entirely clear whether you want an explanation on tree creation in general, on some tree implementation you have found, or you have a basic code already that you cannot get working. You might want to clarify that :).
Also tree creation in general:
Most explanation and implementation you will find might be "overly" elegant :). So try to imagine a simple linked list first. In that list you have nodes(the elements of the list). A node contains some valuable data and a reference to an other node object. A very simple tree is different only in that a node have more than one reference to other nodes. For example it has a Set of references, its "children".
Here is a VERY crude code only as an example for addChild() or appendChild in your case:

```
public class Node {

private String valueableData;
private Set<Node> children;

public Node(){
    this.children=new HashSet<Node>();
}

public Node (String valueableData){
    this.valueableData=valueableData;
    this.children=new HashSet<Node>();
}

public void addChild(Node node){
    children.add(node);
}

}
```

Now this implementation would be quite horrible (I even deleted the setter/getters), also it would be wise to keep the root nodes reference in some cases, and so on. But you might get the basic idea.

You might wanna create a cycle or recursion to go over the (u,v) integer pairs. You create the root node first then you just addChild() all the other nodes recursively, or create every node first then setChild() them according to your rules.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did get the basic idea,however i added more details for the ease of understanding. Kindly have a look. :)